# how to throw an HttpException in Kotlin - retrofit 2 - unit test

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

I am writing a unit test and I want to throw an HttpException with an error code 409.

This is what I tried but it gives me an error

`Using 'parse(String): MediaType?' is an error. moved to extension function`

This is a kotlin file and Retrofit 2.6.0, and ResponseBody is okhttp3 - 3.12.12

What I have tried

```
 every(call.execute()).thenThrow(HttpException(
            Response.error<Any>(409, ResponseBody.create(
                MediaType.parse("plain/text"), ""
            ))
        ))
```

how can i solve this please

thanks
R

Answer (score 7):

**For Kotlin:**
currently `ResponseBody.create` methods are deprecated (at least in OkHttp3 ver. `4.9.1`). Following extension method can be used:

```
"raw response body as string".toResponseBody("plain/text".toMediaTypeOrNull())
```

Answer (score 4):

i just throw this:

```
 throw HttpException(Response.error<ResponseBody>(500 ,ResponseBody.create(MediaType.parse("plain/text"),"some content")))
```

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered this before. At some point, some dependencies of OkHttp3 changed, and the resulting error message isn't super helpful. What I believe you are looking for is the new `.toMediaType()` Kotlin extension function. So instead of:

```
ResponseBody.create(MediaType.parse("plain/text"), "")
```

Please try:

```
ResponseBody.create("plain/text".toMediaType(), "")
```

You'll likely need to import this extension. If your IDE doesn't automatically suggest it, please try importing via `import okhttp3.MediaType.Companion.toMediaType`.

Comment: Hello thanks for responding, I tried this and when I tried to import, it gives me an error on the import - `Unresolved reference: Companion`

Comment: when I looked at MediaType file it is in Java

Comment: If you type `"plain/text".to`, does the IDE suggest any sort of extension function referencing a media type? It's possible the extension definition could've hopped around locations between iterations of OkHttp3.

Comment: tried that but IDE does not suggest any functions related to media type

Comment: Interesting. If you only have this issue while running unit tests, it may be possible the `testImplementation` is operating under a different OkHttpClient iteration than your typical debug build. I'm using the two versions you listed for OkHttp and Retrofit, and you should continue to use `MediaType.parse()`. If you could post the `dependencies {}` of your app-level gradle file, I might be able to deduce the issue. If you do so, please edit your original question and add them there.

Comment: that was due to the fact that okhttp3 version was too old, i updated to latest version and it gave the option to do .toMediaType(). thank you for ur time